# TestListener with jUnit

Tags: java, junit, automation, automated-tests, testng

I am using testng to run tests. I use TestListenerAdapter to decide what to do `onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult)` and `onTestSuccess(ITestResult testResult)` , for example:

```
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
public class MyTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
   @Override
   public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult) {
   // do something when test is failed 
   }

   @Override
   public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult testResult) {
   // do something when test is successful
   }
}
```

I want to do the same with jUnit as well. I searched that jUnit has equal class called RunListener, and it has `testFailure(Failure failure)`, but it doesn't have something like testSuccess

Can anyone help me with this? How to do the same like testng? Practice example would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about [`RunListener#testFinished(Description description)`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html#testFinished(org.junit.runner.Description))? It looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: it says "Called when an atomic test has finished, whether the test succeeds or fails.", so it is not quite for successful tests only. I only looked at `Description` class, there is method `isTest()`, it doesn't say exactly failed or successful like testng ?!

Comment: With `testFailure(Failure failure)` you should be able to determine if the test passed or not :) And no, dislike testng, the Junit api doesn't provides a lot of information.